Help with Recursive Function for Counting Binary Expressions in Logic Assignment
I'm working on a problem for a logic course, and I could really use some help with defining a recursive function. The task is to define countbinexprs, a function that, given a Boolean expression, returns the number of occurrences of binary sub-expressions. The Boolean expressions follow this grammar:
BExpr ::= bool | (BExpr ∧ BExpr) | (BExpr ∨ BExpr) | (¬BExpr)

In this context, "binary sub-expressions" are expressions of the form (BExpr ∧ BExpr) or (BExpr ∨ BExpr).
The task also requires evaluating this function on the expression ((bool ∧ (bool ∨ bool)) ∧ (¬bool)), and the expected result should be 3.
I'm struggling with structuring the recursion to ensure that only binary sub-expressions (and not expressions wrapped in ¬) are counted. Any tips on setting up this function correctly or ways to think about recursively breaking down the expression?
Thank you for any insights or guidance!
EDIT:
Here's the pseudocode as my attempt for the solution:
def countbinexprs(expression):
    if expression == "bool":
        return 0
    elif expression is of the form (A ∧ B) or (A ∨ B):
        return countbinexprs(A) + countbinexprs(B) + 1
    elif expression is of the form ¬A:
        return countbinexprs(A)

This function should cover all cases for counting binary connectives. Let me know if this looks correct or if there are any adjustments I should make!

Which case of the recursion are you stuck on? At least bool should be clear, right?

@NaïmFavier For countbinexprs, this base case would simply return 0 because bool by itself is not a binary sub-expression (it doesn’t involve ∧ or ∨)? As for the recursive cases I’m a bit uncertain about are those involving expressions like (BExpr ∧ BExpr) or (BExpr ∨ BExpr). Specifically, I’m unsure how to structure the recursion to correctly.

If $A$ and $B$ have $n$ and $m$ binary connectives respectively, how many does $A \land B$ have? How about $A \lor B$?

@NaïmFavier The expression A∧B itself is a binary expression, so we add 1 to the total count of binary connectives. Therefore, A∧B has n+m+1 binary connectives. Similarly, A∨B is also a binary expression, adding 1 to the total count of binary connectives. So, A∨B also has n+m+1 binary connectives. So with this recursive rule, we can calculate the number of binary connectives by summing the counts of each sub-expression and adding 1 for each binary connective at the top level of a conjunction or disjunction.

So far so good. Following @NaïmFavier guidance: if A have $n$ binary connectives, how many does $\neg A$?
once this question is answeed you only have to gather every parts to define your recursive function. You can post your try as Edit of your function if you are unsure of the result.

@wece I made an edit, does it work as an answer to the problem?

This looks brillant to me ! Well done.
